# Limit OpenSSL server Cipher options

Tags: encryption, openssl

In our current environment, security runs scans looking for vulnerabilities. One issue keeps coming up with OpenSSL (current release), 4-5 ciphers are below the 128kb encryption level and flags the scanners.

Knowing that the client must specify the options, there are cases where it would be good to limit the server from accepting a selection of the low ciphers. If this can be done, then it would not matter what the client requests. Would it make sense to have a configuration option on what to accept?

In my specific case we are trialing a beta software for file transfer, it pulls the openSSL ciphers into its client. There is currently no option to restrict this.

I also have a similar question out to the beta software developer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list()` to limit the list of ciphers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

// List of allowed ciphers in a colon-seperated list. Example limits ciphers to AES-256 only
const char *allowedCiphers = "AES256-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA38:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256";

bool SetCiphers(SSL *sslContext, const char *ciphers);

int main()
{
   // Create a ssl context here etc.
   SSL *ssl = ...;

   // Set the allowed ciphers
   if (!SetCiphers(ssl, allowedCiphers))
      exit(-1);

   // Process...
   return 0;
}

bool SetCiphers(SSL *sslContext, const char *ciphers)
{
   if (SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(sslContext, ciphers) != 1)
   {
      std::cerr << L"[SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list] failed; could not find a suitable cipher in the provided list of ciphers \"" 
         << ciphers << "\"." << endl;
      return false;
   }
   return true;
}
```

Run `openssl ciphers -v` in a shell for a list of supported ciphers on your system.