# Disable DES in my https server

Tags: c++, c, ssl, openssl

have a light http server (embedded software solution). This http server is calling openssl functions to handle https connexions.

I want to disable the DES cipher in my https server so I find the function:

```
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(SSL_CTX *ctx, const char *str);
```

I m newbie in openssl and I want to find the right string to pass in the function `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list()`

What's the string to use in `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list()` in order to disable DES in my server?

Is it correct to call the `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list()` just after `ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);` ?

Comment: Please study [man ciphers](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html). It boils down to `...:!DES' for disabling DES but note that 3DES is not the same as DES and you probably want to disable this too. Please see https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS for useful cipher strings.

Answer (score 0):

I found an example of `SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list` usage in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18449332/limit-openssl-server-cipher-options).

Summarizing you should declare an string of algorithms using `:` as separators between them (you  can consult the algorihtm names in [wiki openssl](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Ciphers(1))) and create the context before (as you suggested) setting the cypher list. A little example in code:

```
// List of allowed ciphers in a colon-separated list.
const char *allowedCiphers = "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:AES256-GCM-SHA384";
int main()
{
  const SSL_METHOD *method;
  SSL_CTX *ctx;

  method = SSLv23_server_method();
  ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);    
  // Set the allowed ciphers
  if (SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, ciphers) != 1)
  {
    //define error
  }
  SSL_CTX_free(ctx);
  cleanup_openssl();
  return 0;
}
```

Finally I would suggest change your version of openSSL if the library allows DES method, because, as you can see in [this proposal](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/3717), DES is disabled by default except if you compile explicitly. So, I highly recommend update your openSSL version.